# error URL font DOMPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf

En una app que estoy desarrollando de manera local, he instalado DOMPDF. En local no tengo ningún problema.

He subido el proyecto a un servidor y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Undefined index: /var/www/vhosts/xxxx.com/yyyy.aaaaaa.com/vendor/dompdf/dompdf\lib\fonts\Helvetica-BoldOblique
```

resulta que la url no es correcta, no sé donde puedo modificar la url de donde pilla esa font :(

Resulta que var es una carpeta que tengo en la raiz de mi servidor, pero la app no se encuentra ahí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La ruta esta incorrecta porque DomPdf no funciona como un blade.

Prueba a poner el parametro public_path() delante para acceder a tu carpeta publica

```
<link href="{{ public_path() . '/lib/fonts/Helvetica-BoldOblique' }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: muchas gracias! justo lo que necesitaba!!